# Django edit auth user profile

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-authentication

I'm new to `Django` and writing an application in Django 1.11.

I want to create a `Profile update` page.

I have created an app `accounts` to manage all profile related activities and created a class

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, UpdateView


class ProfileView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'accounts/profile.html'


class ChangePasswordView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'accounts/change_password.html'


class UpdateProfile(UpdateView):
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    template_name = 'accounts/update.html'
```

and in `myapp/accounts/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
    url(r'^profile/', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
    url(r'^change_password/', views.ChangePasswordView.as_view(), name='change_password'),
    url(r'^update/', views.UpdateProfile.as_view(), name='update'),
    url(r'^setting/', views.SettingView.as_view(), name='setting')
]
```

When I access `127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/update`, It gives

```
AttributeError at /accounts/update/

Generic detail view UpdateProfile must be called with either an object pk or a slug.
```

Since, I want the logged in user to edit his/her profile information. I don't want to pass `pk` in the url.

**How to create profile update page in Django 1.11?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class UpdateProfile(UpdateView):
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    template_name = 'accounts/update.html'

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

As the error told you, you have to return a pk or slug if you're not precising the object. So by overridding the get_object method, you can tell to django which object you want to update.

If you prefer to do it on another way, you can send the pk or slug of the object in the url :

```
url(r'^update/(?P<pk>\d+)', views.UpdateProfile.as_view(), name='update')
```

Here the default `get_object` method will catch the pk in the args and find the user you want to update.

Note that the first method works only (as i wrote it) if a user want to update his profile and is authenticated (`self.request.user`) and the second way allows you to actually update whatever user you want, as soon as you have the pk of this user (`accounts/update/1`, will update user with the pk=1, etc...).

Some doc [here](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/), get_object() section

> Returns the object the view is displaying.
>       By default this requires `self.queryset` and a `pk` or `slug` argument
>       in the URLconf, but subclasses can override this to return any object.

Comment: I get this working. But how to redirect user based on whether data updated or not. I can see, that data is updating and asking for redirect URL.

Comment: what do you mean? you want to redirect the user after update (or not if i understand) to where? If it's a long stuff, consider asking another question cause this one answer to your problem